# Is there a way to find out the name of the file stdout is redirected to in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, filenames, io-redirection

I know how to detect if my Python script's `stdout` is being redirected (`>`) using `sys.stdout.isatty()` but is there a way to discover what it's being redirected to?

For example:

```
python my.py > somefile.txt
```

Is there a way to discover the name `somefile.txt` on both Windows and Linux?

Comment: If you're interested in the name of the TTY, there's `os.ttyname(fd)`, which works when `os.isatty(fd)` is `True`, and like it, works only on Unix.

Comment: What are you going to do with the information?

Comment: @karl - It's for logging purposes.

Comment: [Hot to print filename of file that is redirected as input in shell](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1734243/995714)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I doubt you can do that in a system-independent way. On Linux, the following works:

```
import os
my_output_file = os.readlink('/proc/%d/fd/1' % os.getpid())
```

Comment: Thanks!, works a treat on Linux. I see what you mean about getting it to work in a platform independent way.

Comment: Note that the result from this readlink seems to be intended mostly for display purposes: If the file is deleted, it will be suffixed with `" (deleted)"` or if it is an anonymous pipe, you might get a name like `"pipe:[1162005]"`.

Answer (score 1):

If you need a platform-independent way to get the name of the file, pass it as an argument and use argparse (or optparse) to read your arguments, don't rely on shell redirection at all.

Use `python my.py --output somefile.txt` with code such as:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--output', # nargs='?', default=sys.stdout,
                    type=argparse.FileType('w'), 
                    help="write the output to FILE", 
                    metavar="FILE")

args = parser.parse_args()
filename = args.output.name
```

If knowing the name is optional and used for some weird optimization, then use Igor Nazarenko's solution and check that `sys.platform` is `'linux2'`, otherwise assume that you don't have the name and treat it as a normal pipe.