# Get path to the file STDOUT is redirected to in PHP command line script

Tags: php, command-line

I have a PHP script run from the command line like this: php test.php >> output.log.
My output.log file has increased in size and I would like to implement some sort of rotation (archiving and truncating it when a certain condition is met).
How can I do this, if I don't know the path to the file from within the code of the script, because it's set when it's called?

I see you can do it in Python as explained here: [Is there a way to find out the name of the file stdout is redirected to in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5943778/is-there-a-way-to-find-out-the-name-of-the-file-stdout-is-redirected-to-in-pytho)

Answer (score 1):

You can't, at least not using `>>`, because that way PHP does not know where its output goes.

You'd have to implement it in PHP itself.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Maybe the Python link gives someone else a clue.