# Is there a way to find out the name of the file stdout is redirected to in Perl?

Tags: perl

Same question as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5943778/is-there-a-way-to-find-out-the-name-of-the-file-stdout-is-redirected-to-in-pytho) written for Python, but asking again for Perl since - well - they are different scripting languages and perhaps different feature sets.

In general, I want to detect if my Perl script's `STDIN` our `STDOUT` is being redirected (preferably the former). Instead of knowing the filename, I'd rather want to know if the caller is using redirection so that I can present them with a 'help text' if they're not.

Preferably platform independent, but I only foresee this script being run on macOS or Linux.

Answer (score 6):

You can check if a handle is a terminal or not using [`-t`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html).

```perl
if (-t STDOUT) {
   say "Terminal";
} else {
   say "Not a terminal or an error occured"; 
}
```

or

```perl
defined( my $rv = -t STDOUT )
   or die("Can't check if STDOUT is a terminal: $!\n");

if ($rv) {
   say "Terminal";
} else {
   say "Not a terminal"; 
}
```

---

Terminal or not, you can find out the kind of file it is.

```perl
stat(STDOUT)
   or die("Can't stat STDOUT: $!\n");

if    (-f _) { say "Plain file";       }
elsif (-p _) { say "Pipe";             }
elsif (-S _) { say "Socket";           }
elsif (-c _) { say "Character device"; }
elsif (-b _) { say "Block device";     }
else         { say "Something exotic"; }  # Impossible?
```

A terminal will be a character device, but not all character devices are terminals.

---

It isn't possible to determine to which file associated (if it even has a name) in a system-independent fashion (if at all), modules aside.

On Linux, you can use `/proc`

```sh
$ perl -e'warn readlink("/proc/$$/fd/".fileno(STDOUT))."\n"'
/dev/pts/0

$ perl -e'warn readlink("/proc/$$/fd/".fileno(STDOUT))."\n"' >a
/tmp/ikegami/a

$ perl -e'unlink "a";
          warn readlink("/proc/$$/fd/".fileno(STDOUT))."\n"' >a
/tmp/ikegami/a (deleted)

$ perl -e'warn readlink("/proc/$$/fd/".fileno(STDOUT))."\n"' |cat
pipe:[27807]
```

Answer (score 5):

```
$ perl -le'print(-t STDIN ? "terminal" : "file")'
terminal
$ perl -le'print(-t STDIN ? "terminal" : "file")' < /dev/null
file
$
```

Comment: Cool. Could you add a bit of explanation on what `-t` does and where to find that? Is it `perldoc perlop` or such? Does it work the same for stdout?

Comment: @Robert `perldoc -f -X`

Comment: Just because it's not a terminal doesn't mean it's a file... could be a pipe or even socket.